# how can get dropdown selected value in textbox in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

i want selected value in input text field in jsp how to do please help? I am new with jsp.

```html
<select class="leavetype" name="leavetype">
    <option value="10">CL</option>
    <option value="7">ML</option>
    <option value="12">SL</option>
    <option value="20">EL/PL</option>
    <option value="5">CPL</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="leave"/>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, but to get the selected value using Javascript refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript  **or** do you mean when posted to a servlet?

Comment: when you submit the form, the value of the selected option will be passed to your controller :) simple as that. What backend are you using? pure servlets or a framework?

Comment: You are using normal html tag , so i guess you are also using javascript. So try to look getting and settting values via js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve through javascript by using onChange function. Within in function need to do like this `document.getElementById ("leave").value = data.value;`

[Refer this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918377/how-to-display-the-corresponding-values-in-the-text-box-depending-on-drop-down-l?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

See this video:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89rRD04QZE4

Hope so it will help you.

In jsp page you may write. ${param.leavetype}.